# order_by working fine in sqlite but not in postgres

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a model with replies and in template the replies with highest upvote should come first.

In my local machine its coming correctly however on server replies are filtered based on FK of upvote field.

**Model:**

```
class solution(models.Model):
    doubt=models.ForeignKey(doubts,related_name='answers')
    reply=models.TextField()
    snapshot = models.FileField(upload_to='support',null=True,blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,null=True,blank=True)
    upvote = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='upvoteuser')

    @property
    def total_upvotes(self):
        return self.upvote.count()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.doubt)
```

**view**

```
def ticketdetails(request,slug,pk):
    ticketis=doubts.objects.get(pk=pk)
    replies = ticketis.answers.all().order_by('-upvote')


    if request.method== 'POST':
        form=replyform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_form=form.save(commit=False)
            new_form.user=request.user
            new_form.doubt=ticketis
            new_form.save()
            form=replyform()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('ticketdetail',kwargs={'slug':ticketis.slug,'pk':ticketis.id}),messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS,'Response submitted succesfully.'))
    else:
        form=replyform()    
    return render(request,'ticketview.html',{'ticketis':ticketis,'replies':replies,'form':form})
```

Comment: What part of the upvote model are you trying to order on? does that have any ordering specified?

Comment: Upvote field with most upvotes count should be first.

Answer (score 2):

> Upvote field with most upvotes count should be first.

This isn't what your ordering is doing, at all

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#order-by):

> If you try to order by a field that is a relation to another model, Django will use the default ordering on the related model, or order by the related model’s primary key if there is no Meta.ordering specified.

If you're trying to order by the count of something then you'll need to annotate it first and then order based on that

Your view is talking about a different model to the one you've shown but the solution will still look similar to below

```
 Solution.objects.annotate(upvote_count=Count('upvote')).order_by('upvote_count')
```

Comment: @PulkitSharma - Pure luck.

Comment: Local machine works with your code either because it's pure luck or because you are using a lesser RDBMS. Postgresql is much closer to standard compliance and sqlite